# My ffmpeg stops streaming after a few seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I am using ffmpeg. I type this in a DOS Prompt:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.8:554/video_1 -an -f image2pipe -vf fps=fps=6 -qscale 0 -
```

It works but then just stops.

So, I amended this to produce an error output file:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.8:554/video_1 -an -f image2pipe -vf fps=fps=6 -qscale 0 - 2>log.txt
```

The log file contents gives me this:

```
ffmpeg version N-69779-g2a72b16 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavformat    56. 21.100 / 56. 21.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.100 /  5. 11.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.17:554/video_1':
  Metadata:
    title           : YOKO Live Streaming
    comment         : video_1
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 352x288 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
Output #0, image2pipe, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    title           : YOKO Live Streaming
    comment         : video_1
    encoder         : Lavf56.21.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 352x288 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 6 fps, 6 tbn, 6 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.22.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    7 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      95kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate= 774.8kbits/s    
frame=   10 fps=9.6 q=0.0 size=     142kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate= 775.1kbits/s    
frame=   13 fps=8.4 q=0.0 size=     189kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate= 776.1kbits/s    
frame=   17 fps=8.1 q=0.0 size=     253kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate= 775.7kbits/s    
frame=   20 fps=7.7 q=0.0 size=     300kB time=00:00:03.16 bitrate= 775.8kbits/s    
frame=   23 fps=7.4 q=0.0 size=     347kB time=00:00:03.66 bitrate= 775.3kbits/s    
frame=   26 fps=7.2 q=0.0 size=     394kB time=00:00:04.16 bitrate= 775.6kbits/s    
frame=   29 fps=7.0 q=0.0 size=     442kB time=00:00:04.66 bitrate= 775.4kbits/s    
frame=   32 fps=6.9 q=0.0 size=     489kB time=00:00:05.16 bitrate= 775.4kbits/s    
frame=   35 fps=6.8 q=0.0 size=     536kB time=00:00:05.66 bitrate= 775.3kbits/s    
frame=   38 fps=6.6 q=0.0 size=     584kB time=00:00:06.16 bitrate= 775.6kbits/s    
frame=   42 fps=6.7 q=0.0 size=     647kB time=00:00:06.83 bitrate= 775.6kbits/s    
frame=   45 fps=6.7 q=0.0 size=     694kB time=00:00:07.33 bitrate= 775.8kbits/s    
frame=   48 fps=6.6 q=0.0 size=     742kB time=00:00:07.83 bitrate= 775.9kbits/s    
frame=   51 fps=6.5 q=0.0 size=     789kB time=00:00:08.33 bitrate= 775.9kbits/s    
frame=   54 fps=6.5 q=0.0 size=     837kB time=00:00:08.83 bitrate= 775.8kbits/s
```

{I reached max of bidy lenght so had to delete some lines}

```
frame=  544 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8583kB time=00:01:30.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  547 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8630kB time=00:01:31.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  550 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8677kB time=00:01:31.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  553 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8725kB time=00:01:32.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  556 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8772kB time=00:01:32.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  559 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8819kB time=00:01:33.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  562 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8867kB time=00:01:33.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  565 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8914kB time=00:01:34.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  569 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    8978kB time=00:01:34.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  572 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9025kB time=00:01:35.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  575 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9073kB time=00:01:35.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  578 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9120kB time=00:01:36.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  581 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9167kB time=00:01:36.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  584 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9215kB time=00:01:37.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  587 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9262kB time=00:01:37.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  590 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9310kB time=00:01:38.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  594 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9373kB time=00:01:38.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  597 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9420kB time=00:01:39.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  600 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9468kB time=00:01:39.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  603 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9515kB time=00:01:40.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  606 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9563kB time=00:01:40.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  610 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9626kB time=00:01:41.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  613 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9673kB time=00:01:42.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  616 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9721kB time=00:01:42.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  619 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9768kB time=00:01:43.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  622 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9815kB time=00:01:43.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  625 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9863kB time=00:01:44.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  629 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9926kB time=00:01:44.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  632 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=    9974kB time=00:01:45.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  635 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10021kB time=00:01:45.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  638 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10069kB time=00:01:46.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  641 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10116kB time=00:01:46.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  644 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10163kB time=00:01:47.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  647 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10211kB time=00:01:47.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  651 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10274kB time=00:01:48.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  654 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10322kB time=00:01:48.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  657 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10369kB time=00:01:49.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  660 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10417kB time=00:01:49.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  663 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10464kB time=00:01:50.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  667 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10527kB time=00:01:51.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  670 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10574kB time=00:01:51.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  673 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10622kB time=00:01:52.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  676 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10669kB time=00:01:52.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  680 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10732kB time=00:01:53.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  682 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10764kB time=00:01:53.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  686 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10827kB time=00:01:54.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  689 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10875kB time=00:01:54.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  692 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10922kB time=00:01:55.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  695 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   10970kB time=00:01:55.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  699 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11033kB time=00:01:56.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  702 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11080kB time=00:01:56.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  705 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11128kB time=00:01:57.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  708 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11175kB time=00:01:57.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  711 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11223kB time=00:01:58.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  714 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11270kB time=00:01:58.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  717 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11318kB time=00:01:59.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  720 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11365kB time=00:01:59.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  724 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11428kB time=00:02:00.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  727 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11475kB time=00:02:01.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  730 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11523kB time=00:02:01.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  733 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11570kB time=00:02:02.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  736 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11617kB time=00:02:02.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  740 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11681kB time=00:02:03.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  743 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11728kB time=00:02:03.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  746 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11775kB time=00:02:04.16 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  749 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11823kB time=00:02:04.66 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  753 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11886kB time=00:02:05.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  756 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11933kB time=00:02:05.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  759 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   11981kB time=00:02:06.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  762 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12028kB time=00:02:06.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  765 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12075kB time=00:02:07.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  768 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12123kB time=00:02:07.83 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  771 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12170kB time=00:02:08.33 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  775 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12233kB time=00:02:09.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  778 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12281kB time=00:02:09.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  781 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12328kB time=00:02:10.00 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  784 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12375kB time=00:02:10.50 bitrate= 776.9kbits/s    
frame=  787 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12423kB time=00:02:11.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  790 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12470kB time=00:02:11.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  793 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12517kB time=00:02:12.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  796 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12564kB time=00:02:12.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  800 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12628kB time=00:02:13.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  803 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12675kB time=00:02:13.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  806 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12722kB time=00:02:14.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  809 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12769kB time=00:02:14.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  812 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12817kB time=00:02:15.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  816 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12880kB time=00:02:15.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  819 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12927kB time=00:02:16.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  822 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   12975kB time=00:02:16.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  825 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13022kB time=00:02:17.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  828 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13070kB time=00:02:17.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  831 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13117kB time=00:02:18.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  834 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13164kB time=00:02:18.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  838 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13228kB time=00:02:19.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  841 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13275kB time=00:02:20.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  844 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13322kB time=00:02:20.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  847 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13370kB time=00:02:21.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  851 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13433kB time=00:02:21.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  854 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13480kB time=00:02:22.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  857 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13528kB time=00:02:22.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  860 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13575kB time=00:02:23.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  863 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13622kB time=00:02:23.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  866 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13670kB time=00:02:24.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  869 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13717kB time=00:02:24.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  873 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13780kB time=00:02:25.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  876 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13828kB time=00:02:25.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  879 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13876kB time=00:02:26.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  882 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13923kB time=00:02:26.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  885 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   13971kB time=00:02:27.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  889 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14034kB time=00:02:28.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  892 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14081kB time=00:02:28.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  895 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14129kB time=00:02:29.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  898 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14176kB time=00:02:29.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  901 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14223kB time=00:02:30.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  904 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14271kB time=00:02:30.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  908 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14334kB time=00:02:31.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  911 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14381kB time=00:02:31.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  914 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14429kB time=00:02:32.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  917 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14476kB time=00:02:32.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  920 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14523kB time=00:02:33.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  923 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14571kB time=00:02:33.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  926 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14618kB time=00:02:34.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  929 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14666kB time=00:02:34.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  933 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14729kB time=00:02:35.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  936 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14776kB time=00:02:35.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  939 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14824kB time=00:02:36.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  942 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14871kB time=00:02:36.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  945 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14919kB time=00:02:37.33 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  948 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   14966kB time=00:02:37.83 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  952 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15029kB time=00:02:38.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  955 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15077kB time=00:02:39.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  958 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15124kB time=00:02:39.50 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  961 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15171kB time=00:02:40.00 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  965 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15234kB time=00:02:40.66 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  968 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15282kB time=00:02:41.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  971 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15329kB time=00:02:41.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame=  974 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15376kB time=00:02:42.16 bitrate= 776.8kbits/s    
frame=  977 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15424kB time=00:02:42.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame=  980 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15471kB time=00:02:43.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame=  984 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15534kB time=00:02:43.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame=  987 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15581kB time=00:02:44.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame=  990 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15628kB time=00:02:44.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame=  993 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15676kB time=00:02:45.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame=  996 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15723kB time=00:02:45.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1000 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15787kB time=00:02:46.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1003 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15834kB time=00:02:47.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1007 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15897kB time=00:02:47.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1010 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15945kB time=00:02:48.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1013 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   15992kB time=00:02:48.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1016 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16039kB time=00:02:49.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1019 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16087kB time=00:02:49.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1022 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16134kB time=00:02:50.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1026 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16197kB time=00:02:50.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1029 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16245kB time=00:02:51.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1032 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16292kB time=00:02:51.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1035 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16340kB time=00:02:52.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1038 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16387kB time=00:02:52.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1042 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16450kB time=00:02:53.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1045 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16498kB time=00:02:54.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1048 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16545kB time=00:02:54.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1051 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16592kB time=00:02:55.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1054 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16639kB time=00:02:55.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1058 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16703kB time=00:02:56.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1061 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16750kB time=00:02:56.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1064 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16797kB time=00:02:57.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1067 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16845kB time=00:02:57.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1070 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16892kB time=00:02:58.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1073 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16940kB time=00:02:58.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1076 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   16987kB time=00:02:59.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1080 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17050kB time=00:02:59.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1083 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17098kB time=00:03:00.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1086 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17145kB time=00:03:00.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1089 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17192kB time=00:03:01.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1092 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17240kB time=00:03:01.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1095 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17288kB time=00:03:02.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1099 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17351kB time=00:03:03.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1102 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17398kB time=00:03:03.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1105 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17445kB time=00:03:04.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1108 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17493kB time=00:03:04.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1111 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17540kB time=00:03:05.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1115 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17604kB time=00:03:05.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1118 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17651kB time=00:03:06.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1121 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17698kB time=00:03:06.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1124 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17746kB time=00:03:07.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1127 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17793kB time=00:03:07.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1130 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17840kB time=00:03:08.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1133 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17888kB time=00:03:08.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1137 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17951kB time=00:03:09.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1140 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   17998kB time=00:03:09.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1143 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18046kB time=00:03:10.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame= 1147 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18109kB time=00:03:11.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1150 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18156kB time=00:03:11.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1153 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18204kB time=00:03:12.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1156 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18251kB time=00:03:12.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1159 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18298kB time=00:03:13.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1163 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18362kB time=00:03:13.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1166 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18409kB time=00:03:14.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1169 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18456kB time=00:03:14.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1172 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18504kB time=00:03:15.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1176 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18566kB time=00:03:15.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1179 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18614kB time=00:03:16.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1182 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18661kB time=00:03:16.83 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1185 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18709kB time=00:03:17.33 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1189 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18772kB time=00:03:18.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1192 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18819kB time=00:03:18.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1195 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18867kB time=00:03:19.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1198 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18914kB time=00:03:19.50 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1201 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   18961kB time=00:03:20.00 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1205 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19025kB time=00:03:20.66 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1208 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19072kB time=00:03:21.16 bitrate= 776.7kbits/s    
frame= 1211 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19119kB time=00:03:21.66 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1214 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19166kB time=00:03:22.16 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1218 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19229kB time=00:03:22.83 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1221 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19277kB time=00:03:23.33 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1224 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19324kB time=00:03:23.83 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1228 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19387kB time=00:03:24.50 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1231 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19435kB time=00:03:25.00 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1234 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19482kB time=00:03:25.50 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1237 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19529kB time=00:03:26.00 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1240 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19577kB time=00:03:26.50 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1244 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19639kB time=00:03:27.16 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1247 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19687kB time=00:03:27.66 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1251 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19750kB time=00:03:28.33 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1254 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19797kB time=00:03:28.83 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1257 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19844kB time=00:03:29.33 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1260 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19891kB time=00:03:29.83 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1264 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   19954kB time=00:03:30.50 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
frame= 1267 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20001kB time=00:03:31.00 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1270 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20049kB time=00:03:31.50 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 18 packets
frame= 1273 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20096kB time=00:03:32.00 bitrate= 776.6kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1276 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20144kB time=00:03:32.50 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1279 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20191kB time=00:03:33.00 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1283 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20254kB time=00:03:33.66 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1286 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20302kB time=00:03:34.16 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1289 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20349kB time=00:03:34.66 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 9 packets
[rtsp @ 04383280] RTP timestamps don't match.
[rtsp @ 04383280] Received packet without a start chunk; dropping frame.
    Last message repeated 8 times
frame= 1293 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20412kB time=00:03:35.33 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1296 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20459kB time=00:03:35.83 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1299 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20507kB time=00:03:36.33 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1303 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20570kB time=00:03:37.00 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1306 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20617kB time=00:03:37.50 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1309 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20665kB time=00:03:38.00 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1312 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20712kB time=00:03:38.50 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1315 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20759kB time=00:03:39.00 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1318 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20807kB time=00:03:39.50 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
frame= 1322 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20870kB time=00:03:40.16 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
frame= 1325 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20917kB time=00:03:40.66 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 4 packets
[rtsp @ 04383280] Missing packets; dropping frame.
frame= 1329 fps=6.0 q=0.0 size=   20980kB time=00:03:41.33 bitrate= 776.5kbits/s    
[NULL @ 0437efe0] RTP: missed 5 packets
```

What else can I do to detect my problem?  Is it the case stream is 'over-whelming' my network connections or..?

Comment: Hm, I guess that you're dropping quite a lot of packets in the local network, and that causes ffmpeg to lose synchronization of the stream and subsequently stop decoding. No error message? Does it just stop? Do you need RTP? Not a big expert on RTP streaming in general, but perhaps a TCP-based streaming method would work?

Comment: Hi, I can use vlc ok. It does stop. It may resume after a time. To switch to tcp or rtp do I just change the protocol? I am not near my PC to try it at the moment so as you are 'around' I thought I ask

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to force ffmpeg to be more resilient against errors and just continue to decode. Maybe you also want to ask your question on the ffmpeg-user mailing list? https://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user

Comment: I  waiting for my registration to go through so I can ask. I will download ispy and see how he does it too

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it solved by using "-re" option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).